# Keep leading zeros when exporting html table to excel with xlsx format

Tags: html, html-table, export-to-excel, xlsx

I have an html table contains data from a table in database. It has a column namely No. HP (Phone number in English).

It can be exported to excel with xlsx format. But, after I have exported it, when I open excel app contains it, the leading zeros are disappeared.

For example, there is a phone number in this html table such as, `0812345`, but after I have exported it, the number becomes `812345` in excel app contains exported table. How to keep the leading zeros so that when I have exported it, the leading zeros are still appeared?

My codes are shown below.

Calling libraries src

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Database Online</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="shim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Blob.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="FileSaver.js"></script>

<body bgcolor="#ededed">
```

---

Link to Export Data

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#444444;" onclick="export('xlsx');">Export Data</a>
```

---

Export function

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function export(type, fn, dl) 
    {
        var elt = document.getElementById('data_table_print_id');
        var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(elt, {sheet:"Data Peserta SW"});
        return dl ?
        XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:type, bookSST:true, type: 'base64'}) :         
        XLSX.writeFile(wb, fn || ('Data Peserta SW.' + (type || 'xlsx')));
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Are the phone numbers `number` values? if so, you should make them into `string` values before you export them. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp

Comment: Note that  a phone number as `string` will always lose its leading zero when converted to `number` value.  The phone number is coming from the DB, so which type has the column of the table? I guess it's a `VARCHAR` column? That means that somewhere in your code the value is converted to `number`.

Comment: @jrswgtr The phone numbers in this table are varchar values

Comment: then it is converted into a number value somewhere. Which variable in your js export function represents the phone number?

Comment: @jrswgtr 'elt' variable represents the phone numbers in html table